# What one should do when they see a"bad" edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

Today, I've seen an answer edit, which "corrected" two perfectly spelt words into wrong spelling. These two "corrections" were all that was changed in the answer. The answer was not mine. Also I can't be sure, but it didn't feel like a vandalism to me, I think this could be a honest mistake.

It's not often, when you see an edit that is *clearly*  and totally wrong, most of the time it's quite subjective.

I'd like to know, what do you do, and what one expected to do with perceived "bad" edits? You can't flag an edit as far as I know. Should be they just let be?

Comment: Roll it back (if you have edit privileges).

Comment: This situation is easy to reproduce: a question or answer with several things that need fixing, and two simultaneous editors. One editor, very thorough, fixes everything and commits. The second editor, working with the original, fixes a few things and commits. The original post's mistakes appear to be _introduced_ by the second editor, when in reality they just _weren't fixed_ by the second editor. One more reason to be thorough when editing, so you don't look like you ever introduce sms-typing or ridiculous punctuation should your edit come second. (Not your example, but sometimes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see a wrong edit, the only correct response is to correct it (either by means of manual improvement, or using the rollback feature,) if you have that ability. Otherwise you can post it on meta, or flag it with a remark.

Do you have a link to the answer?

Comment: Actually, it's already corrected. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6329132/2

Comment: @zespri, even better but thanks for the link.